# prevent delete on child records trigger

Tags: apex

I'm trying to write a trigger that will prevent the deletion of a child record if the parent has a status of reviewed.  I'm receiving an unexpected token: '[' at the second SetID and not sure what is causing it.

Test__c is the child and sheet__c is the parent.

```
trigger PreventEntryDeletion on Test__c(before delete) {

    Set < ID > testentry = New Set < ID > ();
    for (test__c tst: trigger.old) {
        testentry.add(tst.sheetid__c);
    }

    set < id > l = new set < id > [Select Id From sheet__c Where status = 'Reviewed'
        and Id IN: testentry
    ];
    For(test__c obja: trigger.old) {
        If(l.contains(obja.sheetid__c))
        obja.addError('You cannot delete a test entry when being reviewed.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to create a set from a list/query is different, you need to add ().

```
Set<T> l = new set<T>([SOQL QUERY]);
```

Basicly, you have to remember that you're initiating a list, through a constructor that takes a list as argument. Have a look at the [Set Class Documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_set.htm#apex_System_Set_constructors).

**Update:**
That syntax is however limited to sObjects. If you want a set of ID, you'll need to populate your set by apex.

```
for(sheet__c s:[SELECT Id FROM sheet__c WHERE status = 'Reviewed' AND Id IN: testentry]){
   l.add(s.id);
}
```

**Or:**

You can abuse the map constructor, which can be done in a single line, but may be considered less readable. Also not sure which approach may be most resource efficient (in ms).

```
l = new map<id,sheet__c>([SOQL QUERY]).keyset();
```

Comment: In the developer console that gives "Invalid initial value type LIST for SET". And in the documentation you'll see that the "T" has to be the same in the list and the set.

Comment: Nice to see you're paying more attention to the details!

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm reading over the set class documentation now.

Answer (score 2):

If the objects are set up with a master-detail relationship, then you can do this without code.

1. Create a rollup summary field on the parent object that is a count of the detail records. I'll call it ChildCount__c.
2. Create a validation rule on the parent object that throws an error message if the the rollup field is changed and the status is Reviewed. The validation rule criteria would be 
   `ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'Reviewed') && ISCHANGED(ChildCount__c)`. (I'm assuming status is a picklist and is a custom field)

Now, this doesn't give you the prettiest of error messages, but it works without having to write any code.

Answer (score -1):

Map has a special constructor that takes a list of SObject but AFAIK Set does not. So you need:

```
Map<Id, sheet__c> m = new Map<Id, sheet__c>([Select Id From sheet__c Where status = 'Reviewed'
    and Id IN: testentry
]);
```

And note that the round brackets are needed too.

You can then use `m.keySet()` to get the set of ID values to use in your logic.